# Spring Boot to implement Micro service : Polling external web service

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

Requirement is to get data from `web service` - login start of day, logout end of day and poll every 30 second.

Once data is received it will be dumped to data store.

**Pseudo code**

```
Class WebServiceClientWrapper{

      private WebServiceClient webServiceclient;
      private String sessionID;
      private UserInfo userInfo;

      public void onStartOfDay () {
           this.sessionId =  webServiceclient.login(userInfo);
      }

     // Poll every 30 seconds
     public String getData() {
        return webServiceclient.getData();
     }
      public void onEndOfDay () {
           webServiceclient.logout(userInfo,sessionID);
      }
}
```

Want to use `spring boot` to implement above functionality as `micro service`, also want to add additional end points like health check so that service will be discover-able and can be monitored from centralized monitoring system.

Is spring boot will be right solution to implement such micro service which does not have any external client and yet needs to exposed rest end point so that it can be monitored ? Is there any micro service related pattern for this problem ?

Comment: wrapped all operation to call web service under endpoints like /login, /logout and /getData and all endpoints will be called by cron job

Comment: also you can use spring eureka and spring actuator for discovery and health check

Comment: Have you tried @EnableScheduling annotation on your application. Then on getData() method add @Scheduled(fixedRate=30000) annotation

Comment: Hmmm that is great suggestion it solves my problem and schedule annotation also supports Cron expression which is what I am looking for,Thanks and Appreciate your response.